# How to compose docker-compose.yml so i can access deamon's container from php?

Tags: docker, casperjs

I need help with Docker.

Lets say I have `docker-compose.yml` version 3 with Nginx+PHP. How do I add image [vitr/casperjs](https://hub.docker.com/r/vitr/casperjs/) so I can call it from PHP like

```
exec('casperjs --version', $output);
```

?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATED**:

It looks like correct answer would be: *It is impossible*.

You need to put PHP and CasperJS (and PhantoJS as well) to the same container to get them work together. It would be nice if someone might proof me wrong and show the better where to do it. Here is smth like working example:

```
FROM nanoninja/php-fpm

ENV PHANTOMJS_VERSION=phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 
ENV PHANTOMJS_DIR=/app/phantomjs

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev wget bzip2

RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/${PHANTOMJS_VERSION}.tar.bz2
RUN tar xvf ${PHANTOMJS_VERSION}.tar.bz2
RUN mv ${PHANTOMJS_VERSION}/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/
RUN rm -rf phantom*

RUN mkdir -p ${PHANTOMJS_DIR}
RUN echo '"use strict"; \n\
  console.log("Hello, world!"); + \n\
  console.log("using PhantomJS version " + \n\
  phantom.version.major + "." + \n\
  phantom.version.minor + "." + \n\
  phantom.version.patch); \n\
  phantom.exit();' \
  > ${PHANTOMJS_DIR}/script.js

RUN  apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
      git \
      python \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
RUN mv casperjs /opt/
RUN ln -sf /opt/casperjs/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q: How to compose docker-compose.yml so i can access deamon's container from php?

A: You could share docker's `unix domain socket` to access daemon's container.

Something like follows:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
    command: docker run --rm vitr/casperjs casperjs --version
```

**test:**

```
# docker-compose up
WARNING: Found orphan containers (abc_plop_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Recreating abc_app_1 ... done
Attaching to abc_app_1
app_1  | 1.1.4
abc_app_1 exited with code 0
```

You can see `1.1.4` was print by execute command `docker run --rm vitr/casperjs casperjs --version` in `app container`.

This is just an example, you can call `docker run --rm vitr/casperjs casperjs --version` in your own `php container` not use `ubuntu:16.04`, still use `exec` in php code and get the output.

**Updated: (2018/11/05)**

First I think some concepts need to be align with you:

- `-d`: this means `start a container in detached mode`, not `daemon`. In docker, when we talk about daemon, it means `docker daemon` which used to accept the connection of `docker cli`, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d).
- `--rm`: this just to delete the temp container after use it, you can also do not use it.

Difference for using `-d` & `no -d`:

- `With -d`: it will run container in detached mode, this means even the container running, the cli command `docker run`, will exit at once & show you a container id, no any log you will see, like next:

  `# docker run -d vitr/casperjs casperjs --version
  d8dc585bc9e3cc577cab15ff665b98d798d95bc369c876d6da31210f625b81e0`
- `Without -d`: the cli command will not exit until the command for container finish, so you can see the output of the command, like next:

  `# docker run vitr/casperjs casperjs --version
  1.1.4`

So, your requirement is want to get the output of `casperjs`, surely you had to use `no -d` mode, I think.

If you accept above concepts, then you can go on to see a workable example:

**folder structure:**

```
abc
├── docker-compose.yml
└── index.php
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  phpfpm:
    container_name: phpfpm
    image: nanoninja/php-fpm
    entrypoint: php index.php
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
exec('docker run vitr/casperjs casperjs --version', $output);
print_r($output);
```

**test:**

```
~/abc# docker-compose up
Starting phpfpm ... done
Attaching to phpfpm
phpfpm    | Array
phpfpm    | (
phpfpm    |     [0] => 1.1.4
phpfpm    | )
phpfpm exited with code 0
```

You can see `1.1.4` was print through php, attention `privileged` & `volumes` are things had to be set.

Comment: Thank you for the afford. Unfortunately i need to point out that `<?php exec('docker run --rm vitr/casperjs casperjs --version', $output); ?>` doesn't work. And another important thing: i want to learn how to call daemon container (`-d` not `-rm`)

Comment: Don't know why cannot work on your side, just update with a workable solution with complete code in case you still need it, see updated post :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @lagom. All that comments you have mad were very useful for me.